# Prevent current WebView from disappearing while new WebView loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I have a NavigationController that contains a stack of WebViews. When the current WebView is clicked, I create a new WebView and push this onto the NavigationController stack with [pushViewController:animated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc). When this new WebView is pushed onto the screen, there's a period of time when the screen is blank because the new WebView is still loading the webpage.

I'm trying to figure out a way where I can delay this push animation until the new WebView has finished loading. This way, the current WebView will still be on the screen, and then then the new WebView can appear instantly. It seems like once I call pushViewController, it starts disappearing.

Is there any way I can override pushViewController so that the current WebView stays on the screen and the new WebView loads in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing to the view controller after the init, push in the [webView:didFinishNavigation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) delegate method.

You can implement functions for [all of the delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) if necessary.